# What IDE to use with Java EE 8

Tags: java

I am trying to start using Java EE and I am using the Java EE 8 first cup tutorial (at https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/usingexamples001.html). It says to download netbeans 8.2 or later, but elsewhere I have seen Oracle no longer supports netbeans 8.2. What IDE should I be using as a beginner whilst being able to work alongside the tutorial?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements.

Comment: Why not a newer version of NetBeans? Or Eclipse? Try them & see. No offence, but why would anyone want to earn Java these days? What do you plan to do with it?